# Why spark stream do not support event triggered stream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm, spark-streaming

Spark stream is basically micro batch. It means it will run periodically to handle a batch of data during that interval.

Some other stream calculation engine like Storm can be trigger by event. It means when some data comes (a event occur), the data will be handled immediately.

I wonder why Spark Stream can not do the same?  For example, some data comes, then spark stream turn it into a RDD immediately and run calculation on it. Is it hard? Or does not make sense? Why have to wait for a while (the interval) then handle the data together.

Comment: Because responding to individual messages isn't a design goal. You want record-by-record processing go with something like Samza. But ponder this, if you will -- your pub/sub system is likely going to batch up messages anyway. Kafka, for example, is going to batch up records and send them to you in micro-batches regardless of how you think you are handling them in your consumer.

Comment: System like Flink or Samza process events as they arrive. Spark processes events in batches. They have different architectures and are designed for different purposes. Flink/Samza have lower latency and lower throughput. But Spark has higher latency and higher throughput. So, you just need to pick a technology according your needs and requirements. If throughput is your priority Spark is what you need. If you need to process data with lower latency go with Flink/Samza.